Ensure secure communication from ESP8266 to web server: concerns about initial certificate request
I'm using an ESP8266 to communicate securely with a web server via WiFiClientSecure, which enables TLS encryption. However, I have a concern regarding the initial request for the server certificate.
To ensure the authenticity of the web server and prevent potential Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attacks, I understand that it's crucial to verify the server certificate. However, due to my specific circumstances, I am unable to use the usual and customary process for validating the chain of trust and the identity of the server, and hard coding the certificate directly into the ESP8266 is not feasible.
My plan is to make an initial request to the web server to obtain and accept the supplied certificate, after which I can establish secure, authenticated communications. However, I'm worried that this first communication, where I request the certificate may be insecure and leave the system vulnerable to an attacker intercepting that initial request.
How significant is this vulnerability?
What best practices can I follow to secure this initial certificate request, or enhance the overall security of the communication process?
Thank you for your insights!

The only way to ensure this is to physically access the server and copy the certificate to it using a medium (for example, a USB stick or DVD-ROM) via the local console. There is no other way.

You don't need the certificate on the client to verify it, only the corresponding CA certificate.

@GeraldSchneider Hello, thanks for your reply. I have been trying to use the Let's Encrypt ISRG root x1 SHA1 fingerprint. But for some reason can't connect to the server.
When I use the domain certificate it works right away. Trying to figure what's going on currentely.

@paladin, it's not an option to do it physically, since I will lose access to the IoT

I've no idea why this question was migrated to stackoverflow. This is cleary not a question for stackoverflow. @Jaime38130 physical access is the only way to go, there is no other way.

@paladin why do you consider that physical access is the only way to go?

Please read about what a "trust chain" is.
